# Decommissioning of nodes in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I got the following exception when i was trying to decommission a live node. There is no reference in the manual saying that i need to stop the data coming into this node. Even then, decommissioning is specified for live nodes.

Can anyone let me know if am doing something wrong or if this is a bug on cassandra part?

Cassandra Version Used : 2.0.3

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:
data is currently moving to this node; unable to leave the ring     at
org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.decommission(StorageService.java:2629)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:111)
    at
com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:45)
    at
com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanIntrospector.invokeM(MBeanIntrospector.java:235)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.PerInterface.invoke(PerInterface.java:138)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanSupport.invoke(MBeanSupport.java:250)
    at
com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at
com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:791)
    at
javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1486)
    at
javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:96)
    at
javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1327)
    at
javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1419)
    at
javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:847)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor28.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)    at
sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)   at
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  at
sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)     at
sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:556)
    at
sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:811)
    at
sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:670)
    at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: Which command did you use?  `nodetool decommission`?

Comment: Yes.I used ./nodetool decommission

Comment: by any chance, are you trying to decommission more than 1 node at a time?

Comment: No. I decommissioned one node at a time. But can you let me know why you are trying to associate decommissioning more than one node at a time with this?

Comment: When you decommission 1 node its key range is split among the rest of the nodes and streamed. During that time those nodes are flagged as "this node is receiving data from another node", since that data is lost if you decommission any of those nodes that is correct. For some reason this is happening to you when decommissioning only one. Is is a new cluster or you added a new node recently?

Comment: Yes . I added two new nodes . But my cleanup was continuously failing on an assertion error. When I checked their source, I found that they throw this when data is checked . Not sure what was happening . My purpose was to add, sync and remove . Didn't want to remove directly the old ones as it was operational and were considered as seeds. So added, allowed it to sync, clean up failed and hence I went for decommissioning. It succeeded in one node. When I went for the last node , I got this problem. I cross checked nodetool status and the previous nodes were not in UL state or available there.